# Why bash need job control?

Tags: bash, process, kill, jobs

Why Unix systems need job control?
So for example, we can use the process number or job number(jobspec) with the `kill` command.

```
$ sleep 101 &
[1] 19
$ sleep 102 &
[2] 20
$ jobs -l
[1]-    19 Running                 sleep 101 &
[2]+    20 Running                 sleep 102 &
$ kill %1
$ kill 20
[1]-  Terminated              sleep 101
$ jobs -l
[2]+    20 Terminated              sleep 102
$
```

But why is there a concept called job number when the process number is already accessible from all shells?

Comment: It's a convenience for interactive use

Comment: Also because a "job" can be a pipeline (which means it has more than one pid) or a compound statement like a loop (in which case some pids in the job can change as the job runs) or execute a script (in which case the individual commands would have their own pids as they ran). In fact, a job can do all of those things *simultaneously*. Without the job id, it would be extremely hard to discover all the constituent pids.

Comment: `bash` has job control, inherited from `csh`, the OLD way. However, if job control were to be removed, old scripts using job control would no longer work. There would be complaints

Comment: @waltinator If job control were to be removed, old guys like me would no longer work either.